# При запуске Ampps выдает ошибку в PHP и Apache . В чем может быть дело?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, сервер, веб-сервер, wamp

При запуске  Ampps выдает ошибку в PHP и Apache . В чем может быть дело ? [image: скрин экрана], и всплывает такое сообщение как на скрине . Я впервые устанавливаю и имею дело с сервером . Прошу помочь . Буду благодарна :)

Comment: Возможно ему не нравятся нелатинские символы в пути.

Comment: То есть "софт" ? Неужто ль это помешало ему , вот зараза , сейчас проверю

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: никакой разницы после смены папки , та же ошибка

Comment: А что у вас в `httpd.conf` написано? там случайно нет кирилицы, и путь до корня сайта указан верно?

Comment: я уже решила эту проблему . Теперь не активируется SQL ‍♂️‍♂️.